# Debugging LINQ Queries

Tags: c#, linq, debugging

We've been doing a lot of work with LINQ lately, mainly in a LINQ-to-Objects sense.  Unfortunately, some of our queries can be a little complicated, especially when they start to involve multiple sequences in combinations.  It can be hard to tell exactly what's going on, when you get queries that start to look like:

```
IEnumerable<LongType> myCompanies =       relevantBusiness.Children_Companies
            .Select(ca => ca.PR_ContractItemId)
            .Distinct()
            .Select(id => new ContractedItem(id))
            .Select(ci => ci.PR_ContractPcrId)
            .Distinct()
            .Select(id => new ContractedProdCompReg(id))
            .Select(cpcr => cpcr.PR_CompanyId)
            .Distinct();

var currentNewItems = myCompanies 
                .Where(currentCompanyId => !currentLic.Children_Appointments.Select(app => app.PR_CompanyId).Any(item => item == currentCompanyId))
                .Select(currentId => new AppointmentStub(currentLic, currentId))
                .Where(currentStub=>!existingItems.Any(existing=>existing.IsMatch(currentStub)));


Items = existingItems.Union(newItems).ToList();
```

etc., etc...

Even when you debug, it can be difficult to tell who's doing what to who and when.  Short of gratuitously calling "ToList" on sequences to get things I can examine more easily, does anyone have any good suggestions for how to debug "complicated" LINQ?

Comment: [This blog post](http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2009/04/23/linq-to-objects-debugging.aspx) has some very promising techniques for debugging LINQ to Objects.

Comment: https://oz-code.com/ but it is paid.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A query like that seems to indicate to me that you're not doing a good job choosing appropriate data structures, or doing a good job with encapsulation and separation of tasks.  I'd suggest taking a look at it and breaking it up.

In general, though, if I want to debug a LINQ query that isn't obviously correct, I'd break it up into subqueries and examine the results one-at-a-time in the debugger.

Comment: Heartily agree.  With LinqToObjects each step in the chain will actually give you an object to work with and examine.  Unlike LinqToSQL where the expression evaluation is delayed until the end, the extension methods in LinqToObjects work just like other methods and evaluate immediately.

Comment: LINQ to Object queries use defered evaluation, too. But you can evaluate them while debuging.

Comment: Is there a way to get the object to 'evaluate now'?  Like if I have an IEnumerable<T> that's deferred, is there some '.Go()' function I can call on it in the debugger to check its current state?

Comment: As for the object structure, the best phrase to describe it is "Legacy Code out of my control".

Comment: GW:  In the Visual Studio 2008 debugger, if execution is stopped with an IEnumerable in scope, you can mouseover the reference and go to "Results" in the menu to evaluate the enumeration.  Alternately, you can just call ToArray().

Comment: LINQ can be an open invitation to pernicious evil - to abandon Separation of Concerns and encapsulation, to increase coupling. etc. etc. Resist overscoping the way you apply it.

Answer (score 17):

I know my answer is "a bit" late, but I had to share this:

Just discovered **[LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/)** and it's AMAZING (not to mention free).
Can't believe I've written Linq for so long without knowing about this tool.

As far as I understand, it's the work of the author(s?) of O'Reilly's ["C# 3.0 in a Nutshell"](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/) and ["C# 4.0 in a Nutshell"](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/) .

Answer (score 9):

When I looked around recently for answers to the very same question I found some intriguing hints here and there but no cohesive narrative really digging into answering the question. So I wrote one myself and it was just published on Simple-Talk.com ([LINQ Secrets Revealed: Chaining and Debugging](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/linq-secrets-revealed-chaining-and-debugging/)). You might need to register to read the article (site seems to be going through some changes in recent days) so here are the highlights of the article:

(1) In LINQPad: Use its extraordinary Dump() method. You can inject this at one or more points in a LINQ chain to see your data visualized in an amazing clean and clear fashion.

(2) In Visual Studio: Embed nop statements in the middle of your LINQ chain so you can set breakpoints. Note the return statement must be on its own line to set a breakpoint in Visual Studio. (Thanks to Eric White’s blog entry [Debugging LINQ Queries](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2008/11/07/debugging-linq-queries.aspx) for this tip.)

```
.Select(z =>
{return z;}
)
```

(3) In Visual Studio: Inject calls to the Dump() extension method I present in my article to allow logging. I started with Bart De Smet's Watch() method in his informative article [LINQ to Objects – Debugging](http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2009/04/23/linq-to-objects-debugging.aspx) and added some labeling and colorization to enhance the visualization, though still it pales in comparison to LINQPad's Dump output.

(4) Finally, (yes I am enamored of LINQPad's Dump method!) bring LINQPad's visualization right into Visual Studio with Robert Ivanc's [LINQPad Visualizer](http://code.google.com/p/linqpadvisualizer/) add-in. Not a perfect solution (no support yet for VS2010, requires classes to be serializable, some rendering issues) but it is quite useful.

**2016.12.01 Update**

Just published on Simple-Talk.com is the sequel to the above article: [LINQ Debugging and Visualization](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/net-development/linq-debugging-visualization/). This article provides thorough coverage of the new LINQ debugging capability of the OzCode extension for Visual Studio 2015. OzCode finally makes LINQ debugging easy and powerful. (And, no, I do *not* work for OzCode :-).

Comment: Good technique to know about!

Comment: and now the visualizer supports both vs2010 and classes that are not serializable! :)

Answer (score 4):

There are no build in tools I am aware of. The best you can do is splitting the query in multiple subqueries and evaluate these subqueries while debuging. A good 3rd party tool is [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/).

Answer (score 4):

I know this is and old question but I have found other solutions that may be useful for somebody. I've struggled with the same problem when debugging LINQ queries. There are 2 good ways how you can debug them.

One way: Change lambda expressions to body expressions. This enables you to place a breakpoint inside. Also you can set some conditions for these breakpoint when you right-click on them so it gives you lots of possibilities. Example:

```
// Instead of this:
var names = new List<string> { "Anna", "Tom", "Jerry" };
var namesLength = names.Select(name => name.Length);

// Use this:
var names = new List<string> { "Anna", "Tom", "Jerry" };
var namesLength = names.Select(name =>
{
    return name.Length; // Set breakpoint here
});
```

Another way: Use Quick Watch in Visual Studio. How? In the example above place a breakpoint where your LINQ query is. When the code stops, select the entire LINQ query with your mouse, right-click on it and select Quick Watch... . It produces the result of any query you place in there using the actual data you have in your program. It supports IntelliSense, too.
One tip: It's usually useful to put a .ToList() at the end of your query in Quick Watch to see the results.

Answer (score 2):

Horse Apples!

Resharper (which I love) suggested I change this

```
foreach (BomObservation initialObservation in initialObservations)
{
    if(initialObservation.IsValid() && !initialObservation.IsStationOnly)
        mappableObservations.Add(initialObservation);
}
```

to this

```
initialObservations.Where(observation => observation.IsValid() && !observation.IsStationOnly).ToList();
```

Yeh it's sexy and sleek but stepping through it and debugging it? You just can't do it. I am going back to foreach for this one.

I love LinqPad too and I do think Linq is pretty awesome in a 'one ring to rule them all' sort of way, but in this scenario I lose something.